# Flask BuildError - Could not build URL for endpoint

Tags: python, html, flask

I've got what should be a very simple python code to select some data from my database

```
@app.route('/studentsearch', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def searchstudent():
    """ Displays the student search page for the site """
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM student")
    all_students = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('studentsearch.html', all_students = all_students)
```

But when I go to render the HTML page i get *werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'studentsearch'. Did you mean 'newstudent' instead?*

My table is also pretty straight forward as well...

```
<table>
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>Student ID:</th>
            <th>First Name:</th>
            <th>Last Name:</th>
            <th>Click to View Student Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        {% for each_result in all_students %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ each_result[0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ each_result[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ each_result[2] }}</td>
                <td>CLICK HERE!!!</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What's going on?  'newstudent' isn't even mentioned within the python or HTML??

As requested here's the code that the 'newstudent' appears to be coming from:

```
def newstudent():
    """Displays the new student page for the site"""
    return render_template('newstudent.html')

@app.route('/process_newstudent', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def process_newstudent():
    """ Processes the data from the new student course """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form['firstname']
        last_name = request.form['lastname']
        year_began = request.form['yearbegan']

        try:
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO student (first_name, last_name, year_began) VALUES ('{}','{}','{}');".format((first_name.title()), (last_name.title()), year_began))
            mydb.commit()
            cursor.close()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            cursor.close()
            return failure('newstudent', f"Error message: {err}. Student not added")
        else:
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM student")
            student_success = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            return render_template('newstudent_success.html', student_success = student_success)
    else:
        request.method == 'GET'
        return render_template('newstudent.html')
```

Comment: can you put up your app.py whole code ?

Comment: @Codenewbie my full app.py code sits around 300 lines deep so I wont put it all up but I've added the code that the 'newstudent' seems to be pulling from

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a dynamic URL somewhere in your application code or HTML code using the *url_for* function?

If you are, then I think what might be happening is that you're passing the parameter *'studentsearch'* to that function instead of *'searchstudent'* (*url_for* builds endpoints using the view function name, not the endpoint name). E.g. within an HTML template the URL in question would be built like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('searchstudent') }}">Search</a>
```